# TSQL for Batting Average formula

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question that states:

> Using a BETWEEN clause, find all players with a Batting Average between .0.300 and 0.3249. The query should return the Full Name (NameGiven (NameFirst) NameLast), YearID, Hits, At Bats and Batting Average sorted by descending batting average.

```
SELECT 
    people.playerid, 
    (nameFirst +' ( '+ nameGiven + ' ) ' + nameLast) AS 'Full Name', 
    yearID, H, AB, 
    CONVERT(decimal(5, 4), h * 1.0 / AB) AS [Batting Average] 
FROM 
    People, Batting
WHERE 
    Batting Average BETWEEN .300 AND 0.3249
ORDER BY
    Batting Average DESC
```

I get a red underline in the `WHERE` clause for Batting Average.

Why is it not recognizing the Batting Average column in the Select?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error is that you did not use the square brackets around the field name like you did in the `SELECT` clause: `[Batting Average]`.

However, you cannot reference aliases from the `SELECT` clause in a `WHERE` clause. The reason is that the `WHERE` clause is evaluated before the expressions in the `SELECT` clause are evaluated. On the other hand, you *can* reference such an alias in the `ORDER BY` clause. But don't forget those brackets.

In the `WHERE` clause you'll have to use the formula on the original fields again.

You should also avoid division by zero. So better check that `AB` is not zero.

Finally, you did not specify a join for the two tables, so your query would produce a Cartesian product. I'll assume that the Batting table has a foreign key called `playerid`.

So taking all those points into consideration, this should be a better query:

```
SELECT     people.playerid, 
           (nameFirst +' ( '+ nameGiven + ' ) ' + nameLast) AS 'Full Name', 
           yearID, 
           H,
           AB, 
           Convert(decimal(5,4), h*1.0/AB) as [Batting Average] 
FROM       People
INNER JOIN Batting ON Batting.playerid = People.playerid
WHERE      AB <> 0
       AND h*1.0/AB BETWEEN .300 AND 0.3249
ORDER BY   [Batting Average] DESC
```